# Deploy setup program with visual studio and create new instance of SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I want to execute the program that the SQL Server Express database needs to run in the system. I created setup with Visual Studio with prerequisites -> SQL Server Express.

The problem I have is that if SQL Server is another version installed on the system, then I will not install SQL Server 2008 Express; how to create a new instance of SQL Server Express in my setup?

Comment: There seem to be two questions, but t's not clear exactly what you're asking. The prerequisite install will just do the right thing and install a higher version if the previous version is lower, and it's all backwards compatible with older versions. Also "creating an instance" - are you referring to an instance name that you create with your app? That part doesn't appear to be install related.

Comment: When I setup with Visual, I have the need for sql express 2008. Some systems will not install sqlexpress2008 when sql is already installed on the system. For this reason, I want to create an instance with a different name to install on the system

Comment: My main problem is that I wrote a c # program with the sqlexpress2008 database and I want to make it work properly on all systems and windows. I also worked with the advanced installer, but I still encountered a lot of problems in windows. I do not know what to do؟ please help me